# map or foreach on an array of objects but only for the fist 5 objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array of objects but I only want to loop through the first 5 objects and break, whats the best way to do that.

```
[
  {"visibility": 10000,},
  {"visibility": 10000,},
  {"visibility": 30000,},
  {"visibility": 40000,},
  {"visibility": 10000,}, -----> exit here
  {"visibility": 20000,},
  {"visibility": 90000,},
  {"visibility": 230000,},
  {"visibility": 10000,},
  {"visibility": 70000,},
]
```

Comment: Have you tried `Array.slice()`?

Comment: _"I only want to loop through the first 5 objects and break"_: have you tried looping through the first 5 objects? `for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++)`?

Answer (score 0):

Just using [**Array.slice()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) can do it

```
console.log(data.slice(0,5))
```

```js
let data = [
  {"visibility": 10000,},
  {"visibility": 10000,},
  {"visibility": 30000,},
  {"visibility": 40000,},
  {"visibility": 10000,},
  {"visibility": 20000,},
  {"visibility": 90000,},
  {"visibility": 230000,},
  {"visibility": 10000,},
  {"visibility": 70000,},
]

console.log(data.slice(0,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

write a below code

```
import React from "react";

const employees = [
 { id: 1, name: "Alice", country: "Austria" },
 { id: 2, name: "Bob", country: "Belgium" },
 { id: 3, name: "Carl", country: "Canada" },
 { id: 4, name: "Delilah", country: "Denmark" },
 { id: 5, name: "Ethan", country: "Egypt" },
 { id: 6, name: "Alice", country: "Austria" },
 { id: 7, name: "Bob", country: "Belgium" },
 { id: 8, name: "Carl", country: "Canada" }
];

function App() {
return (
<>
  <div>
    {employees.slice(0, 4).map((employee, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <h2>name: {employee.name}</h2>
          <h2>country: {employee.country}</h2>

          <hr />
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
 </>
 );
}

export default App;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
name: Alice
country: Austria
---------------------
name: Bob
country: Belgium
---------------------
name: Carl
country: Canada
---------------------
name: Delilah
country: Denmark
---------------------
```

link :- https://codesandbox.io/embed/modest-breeze-71n13n?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this logic :

```js
let arr = [
  {"visibility": 10000,},
  {"visibility": 10000,},
  {"visibility": 30000,},
  {"visibility": 40000,},
  {"visibility": 10000,},
  {"visibility": 20000,},
  {"visibility": 90000,},
  {"visibility": 230000,},
  {"visibility": 10000,},
  {"visibility": 70000,},
];

let newArr = [];

arr.map((obj,index) => {
if(index < 5){
newArr.push(arr[index]);
};

});

console.log(newArr);
```